# How to cut edge of ellipse flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, widget, ellipse

I am going to make this widget in my app but I couldn't cut the edge of my widget like this.

This is what I want to create:

[image: This is what I want to create:]

But this is what I have created:

[image: But this is what I have created:]

I have used a container with a border radius to create this widget.
Can you please suggest a better way to make the above widget as I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Easy solution**: Just wrap your container inside **Transform.scale()** and scale it a little bit so that it cuts from left and right

```
Transform.scale(
     scale: [your scaling factor], // 1 is normal
     child: [YourContainer()],
)
```

**Complex solution**: You can make a *custom clipper* for your container and clip it accordingly.